# boto3 create image using instance id

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, boto3

I am using boto3 with python3 for aws usage, in the aws console there is a very simple option for creating an image from a running / stopped ec2 instance. I am looking for something similar in the boto3 SDK, the closest this I found is how to create an image from the EBS volume like so:

```
session = boto3.Session(...)
ec2 = session.client("ec2") 
ec2.create_image(...)
```

as explained [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_image)

I would like to save the need to find out the volume ID for the instance, and just use the instance ID, is that possible?

I tried to follow [this](https://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.create_image)
Using this code:

```
ec2.create_image(instance_id)
```

But got this error

> TypeError: create_image() only accepts keyword arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass an Instance ID, using the following:

`ec2.create_image(InstanceId=instance_id, Name="abc")`.

Note that this will attempt to reboot your EC2 instance. If you don't want the instance to reboot, use:

`ec2.create_image(InstanceId=instance_id, NoReboot=True, Name="abc")`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and getting this error: Missing required parameter in input: "Name" when adding name its running fine.

Answer (score 2):

When trying the same i got an error ->

> "AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_image'"

so my suggestion is use

```
"boto3.client('ec2').create_image" instead of "ec2.create_image"
```

Comment: ec2 in the other answer assumes ec2=boto3.client('ec2'). So you both are right.

Answer (score 1):

an ec2 instance has no method create_image
create_image belongs to the boto3 client for "ec2" instances, like ...

```
region = 'eu-central-1'
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
client.create_image(InstanceId=<INSTANCEID>,  
Name=<NEWNAME>, NoReboot=True)
```